# ios：My app,first login is alright, logout my app and login is ok, but if I double-click home to kill my app and login, it will crash

Tags: ios, authentication, crash, logout

Recently, I get an old project, after modified some codes, such as `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`, and `ATS` to adapte iOS9.But there comes an issue:
in my app,For first time login is alright, logout my app and again login is ok, but if I double-click home to kill my app and try login, it will crash.

Someone meet with this issue?

## EDIT:I have get the reason, if in iOS8 it works well,but if in the iOS9, it will crash, I also don't get the solution,is the code is too old?

Comment: Add a exception Breakpoint and try doing the same.. You ll get the error spot.. Then share the error description..

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan, I add the exception Breakpoint , and double-click home to kill my app and login again will the exception Breakpoint work for me?

Comment: Oh.. You're getting crash after relogin ? not at the time of killing the app.. ?

Comment: As long as you relaunch the app using Xcode then the exception breakpoint will work.  If the crash occurs when not running under the debugger, you will need to look for the crashlog in the Xcode devices window

Comment: Yeah,after double-click home to kill my app, and relogin,it will show the crash, but if I logout my app and relogin, it will not appear the issue.

Comment: Is it HTTP(s)/webLogin ? if yes, does it set cookies in the the app browser ? if yes, on app launch you have to check if cookie is set and you are already log in.

Comment: @PANKAJ VERMA,  it is app login. origin ios app.

Comment: Then check what does the Logout action do : Is it clearing data from NSUserDefault or Keychain/sharedKeychain which were saved at Login? Since killing the App will not be doing these logout actions and reopening the app and  login again will try to override(rewrite) the stored credentials, which possibly cause crash!

Comment: Sounds attractive， I will have a try.